# Is there any fast method to find the determinant of the following matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

**Is there any fast method (for manual computation by hand) to find the determinant of the matrix**

$$[D \alpha ]_{i,j} = \begin{cases} 
1 + (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i})^2 & ; i = j \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}  & ; i \not = j
\end{cases}, \text{where} \quad i = 1,...,n$$
and $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The matrix is equal to
$$
I + \nabla f \cdot \nabla f^T,
$$
where $\nabla f$ is a column vector,
whose determinant equals
$$
\det(I + \nabla f \cdot\nabla f^T) = \det( 1+ \nabla f^T \nabla f) = 1+ \nabla f^T \nabla f= 1 + \|\nabla f\|_2
^2.
$$
See [Sylvester's determinant identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_identity)

Comment: what does $$||\nabla f ||^2$$ mean ?

Comment: Euclidean norm squared

Comment: $\|x\|^2 = x^Tx$ Euclidean norm squared

Comment: I couldn't understand exactly with property you are using in $\det( 1+ \nabla f^T \nabla f) = 1+ \nabla f^T \nabla f$

Comment: This is just the determinant of a $1x1$ matrix - a number.

Comment: how ? Could you explain your steps more clearly please ?

Comment: After 5 months, I got it :)

Comment: Sometimes it takes time to understand, but then it can be really fast :)